# How do I make a report use RDL code that I updated in the ReportServer db

Tags: reportingservices-2005

In Reporting Services 2005, I need to update an embedded image file in over 300 reports to use a new image (re-branding). 
I was able to come up with a script that changes the RDL to what I want, but when I run the report in Report Manager, it continues to use the old report definition and display the old image. If I download the RDL to a text file, it has my changes. When I re-upload it, the report displays the new image.

I'd like to know if I need to do something else to tell Reporting Services that there is a new definition.

My t-sql statement is below:

```
-- Pull updated image code from a sample report I updated with new logo
DECLARE @NewImageString VARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @NewImageString = SUBSTRING(convert(VARCHAR(max), convert(VARBINARY(max), content)), charindex('<EmbeddedImage Name="logo_1">', convert(VARCHAR(max), convert(VARBINARY(max), content)))
        --calculate length of new image string 
        , 15 + charindex('9k=</ImageData>', convert(VARCHAR(max), convert(VARBINARY(max), content))) --endpoint of new image string
        - charindex('<EmbeddedImage Name="logo_1">', convert(VARCHAR(max), convert(VARBINARY(max), content))) -- beginning point of new image string
    )
FROM reportserver.dbo.CATALOG
WHERE content IS NOT NULL
    AND PATH LIKE '%/Live.Reports%'
    AND NAME LIKE 'rpt_Triage_new%'

-- Replace <EmbeddedImage> portion of RDL
UPDATE ReportServer.dbo.CATALOG
SET CONTENT = convert(IMAGE, convert(VARBINARY(max), SUBSTRING(convert(VARCHAR(max), convert(VARBINARY(max), content)), 0, charindex('<EmbeddedImage Name="logo">', convert(VARCHAR(max), convert(VARBINARY(max), content)))) + @NewImageString + SUBSTRING(convert(VARCHAR(max), convert(VARBINARY(max), content)), 28 + charindex('53KOZjtohn0ICAA7</ImageData>', convert(VARCHAR(max), convert(VARBINARY(max), content))), 200000)))
WHERE PATH LIKE '%/Test1.Reports%'
    AND NAME LIKE 'rptTriage_to_update%'

-- Update <Value> for Image1 reference
UPDATE ReportServer.dbo.CATALOG
SET content = convert(IMAGE, convert(VARBINARY(max), REPLACE(convert(VARCHAR(max), convert(VARBINARY(max), content)), '<Value>logo</Value>', '<Value>logo_1</Value>')))
WHERE content IS NOT NULL
    AND PATH LIKE '%/Test1.Reports%'
    AND NAME LIKE 'rptTriage_to_update%'
    AND convert(VARCHAR(max), convert(VARBINARY(max), content)) LIKE '%<Value>logo</Value>%'
```

Answer (score 0):

If your reports are not organized in many folders and if you can access your reports as http://server/reports,  then delete all existing reports in the folder and upload all the new rdl files. That will make upload rdl files easy.

Comment: Check these links

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlreportingservices/thread/87b26ad4-2df3-4da2-9f3c-7b9721b28ca7/

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlreportingservices/thread/d4ba0d89-8f16-491f-8433-a375eda5627c

Comment: I'd prefer not to download and re-uploading the RDL files. I found a link where TechNet Community Support indicates that what I'm hoping to do isn't really possible: http://msdn.developer-works.com/article/12445648/Report+not+updating+despite+changes+to+ReportServer.dbo.Catalog.Content

Comment: Thanks for the article, it was interesting to know.

Answer (score 0):

My final solution involved using the script above to change the report definitions, then use [RSScripter](http://web.archive.org/web/20120830141644/http://www.sqldbatips.com/samples/code/RSScripter/RSScripter.zip) to bulk download and upload the reports. I didn't realize it before, but RSScripter automatically generates a command file to re-upload the reports.